# What is the political meaning of "shaheed" in India?

Tags: india, terminology

Literally, the word "shaheed" in Arabic means "martyr". But the word also has a more specific political meaning.

In the Middle East, the term "shaheed" often indicates a Muslim suicide bomber acting against a non-Muslim target. 
[Here](http://garhwalpost.in/5th-edition-of-shaheed-memorial-t-20-cricket-tournament-concludes-in-upes/) I found a description of a cricket contest in India, in memory of Shaheed. From the text, it seems that "shaheed" refers to a soldier from the army of India.

Does the term "shaheed" in India just refers to any soldier of India who was killed during service? Or does it have a specific political meaning (e.g. identifying with a specific group/religion in India)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shaheed or [Shahid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahid) means Martyr in India also. In India it applies as Martyr who gave up his/ her life for nation.

> Sikhism The word shahid (Punjabi: ਸ਼ਹੀਦ) is also found in Sikhism, a
>   religion founded by Guru Nanak in the northwest part of the Indian
>   subcontinent (now Pakistan and India). It means a martyr.[30][31][32]
>
> The term was borrowed from the Islamic culture in Punjab when Sikhism
>   was founded, and before the start of the British Raj it referred to
>   the Sikh people who met death at the hands of Muslims.[30] Another
>   related term is shahid-ganj, which means a "place of
>   martyrdom".[30][33]
>
> The most discussed shahid in Sikhism have been two of their Gurus,
>   namely Guru Arjan and Guru Tegh Bahadur for defying Islamic rulers and
>   refusing to convert to Islam.[32] Guru Arjan was arrested under the
>   orders of the Mughal Emperor Jahangir and asked to convert to
>   Islam.[34][35] He refused, was tortured and executed in 1606
>   CE.[34][36] Historical records and the Sikh tradition are unclear
>   whether Guru Arjan was executed by drowning or died during
>   torture.[34][37] His martyrdom, that is becoming a shahid, is
>   considered a watershed event in the history of Sikhism.[34][38]
>
> Guru Tegh Bahadur's martyrdom resulted from refusing to convert and
>   for resisting the forced conversions of Hindus in Kashmir to Islam
>   because he believed in freedom of conscience and human rights.[39] He
>   was publicly beheaded in 1675 on the orders of Mughal emperor
>   Aurangzeb in Delhi.[40][41] Gurudwara Sis Ganj Sahib in Delhi marks
>   the shahid-ganj, or place of execution of the Guru.[42]
>
> The Sikh have other major pilgrimage sites, such as the shahid-ganj in
>   Sirhind, where two sons of Guru Gobind Singh were buried alive by
>   Mughal Empire army in retaliation of their father's resistance. In
>   Muktsar, near a lake is a shahid-ganj dedicated to forty men who died
>   defending Guru Gobind Singh.[33]

India celebrates [Martyr's day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martyrs%27_Day_(India)) also known as **Sarvodaya day**

Although the Sarvodaya Day is celebrated on 30th January on the death anniversary of [Mahatma Gandhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahatma_Gandhi), the greatest martyrs have been **Bhagat Singh**, **Shivaram Rajguru** and **Sukhdev Thapar**, not limited to these.

Comment: I see. So a shaheed may be of any religion - Muslim, Sikh, Hindi, or any other?

Comment: @Erel Yes, I think it is a borrowed word from Arabic, mark it as answer if it answers your question

Comment: I am curious to know - why are Bhagat Singh, Shivaram Rajguru and Sukhdev Thapar "greater" martyrs than Mahatma Gandhi (according to your opinion)?

Answer (score 4):

Shaheed in India means a person who died to save his nation and people.He/she can be anyone from Army men to common civilians.
Shaheed or martyred have same meaning.